# MySQL: Query that finds how many customer of each gender we have in each state

Tags: mysql, group-by

Write a query that finds how many customer of each gender we have in each state

```
select Gender, count(*) as Number_of_each_gender
from Customer_info
group by Gender;
```

This outputs the table I have below, which is correct but I'm missing the in each State part, any help? MySQL

```
Gender   Number_of_each_gender
Male      4
Female    3
```

Comment: Hint: You can group by more than one column.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm a newbie so it takes me some time to fully grasp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add State to the query and Group By

```
SELECT Gender, State, COUNT(*) AS Number_of_each_gender
FROM Customer_info
GROUP BY State, Gender
ORDER BY State,Gender;
```

Comment: I just figured it out right before you answered but I greatly appreciate the help.